# Display different value for each foreach index

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have css class that I don't want to add into every li tag. It should be added into one li and next li should be empty and so on...

I tried to add

for example

```
<?php 

 $css_class = 'class="pull_rigt"';

 echo "<ul>";
 foreach($posts as $key => $value ) {

   echo "<li $css_class>";
    echo $value['data'];
   echo "</li>";

}
echo "<ul>";
?>
```

the output should be

```
<li class="pull_rigt">
    data
<li>
<li>
    data
</li>
```

I tried matching power of two numbers in every foreach index but couldn't figure out the math.

```
<?php 

 $css_class = 'class="pull_rigt"';

 echo "<ul>";

 $i = 0;
 foreach($posts as $key => $value ) {

   <li <?php echo ($i & ($i - 1)) == 0 ? $css_class; ?>

    echo $value['data'];

   echo "</li>";

   $i++;
}
echo "<ul>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont necessarily have to add a class to apply this kind of formulaic styling, if your `li` appear one after another, you can simply style them based on whether they are `odd` or `even` using the following CSS:

```
li:nth-of-type(odd){}
```

or

```
li:nth-of-type(even){}
```

### Example code:

```css
li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm trying to learn to php. knowing css has something like this is good. thanks for your help.

Comment: May be best to remove the `css` tag from the question- as this relates to `php` only in that case

Answer (score 3):

Most simple solution might be using [nth-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp), so that you don't need to use any classes at all.

Or, use % operator in PHP - it means "remainder after division by some number".
The foreach loop could look like this:

```
foreach ($posts as $key=>$value) {

    echo "<li"
    if ($key % 2 == 1) { // For $key 1, 3, 5, 7...
        echo " ".$css_class; 
    }
    echo ">";

    echo $value["data"];

    echo "</li>";
}
```

Use different operands to get different results, i.e. `$key % 3 == 2` would be truthy for $key 2, 5, 8 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I use the modulus operator `%` for these things.

http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic

For simple even/odd evaluations:

**Even:** `$num % 2 == 0`

**Odd:** `$num % 2 == 1`

Here's a standalone example based on your code:

```
<?php 
// Test Data
$posts = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $posts[] = array('data' => $i);
}
echo '
<style type="text/css">
.pull_rigt {
    color: red;
}
</style>';

// UL
echo "<ul>";
$i = 0;
foreach($posts as $key => $value ) {
    $class = ($i % 2 == 0) ? ' class="pull_rigt"' : ''; // Even Numbers
    #$class = ($i % 2 == 1) ? ' class="pull_rigt"' : ''; // Odd Numbers
    echo "<li{$class}>";
    echo $value['data'];
    echo "</li>";
    $i++;
}
echo "<ul>";
?>
```

You can see it working here: http://viper-7.com/t0jUn1